# use resource file based on customername in settings

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on an blazor application that will be used by more than one of our customers.
In case one of those customers wants a certain text different than the others I want to create a resx file for each one of them.

So the file would be called:

```
customer1_global_nl.resx for customer 1
customer2_global_nl.resx for customer 2
..etc..
```

At this moment I have only one file: global_nl.resx

In program I have this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStringLocalizer, StringLocalizer<Global_nl>>();
```

In my code I have this:

```
 var bodyText = Resources.Global_nl.rsNewAccountBody;
```

And I have annotations:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "rsVerplicht", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global_nl), AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
```

Now I am trying to figure out how I can replace each of these locations where I used Global_nl for something that is based on the appsetting "customer"

Is this at all possible? Any ideas?

An alternative would be to write some script that in a pre-build event copies the file "customer1_global_nl.resx" to write over "global_nl.resx", but it would be awesome if it could be done in code.